# Why my htaccess rules do not work perfectly?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I want to make 2 types of URL with these styles using htaccess and mod_rewrite.

```
http://www.site.com/product
http://www.site.com/product/1/something
```

For this, I've added these lines to the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&des=$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [F]
```

But whenever I run my application and hint **http://localhost/project/**, web server redirect me to **http://localhost/**.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I redirect to localhost and why the codes above do not work ?
2. How can I add a trailing slash to the end of clean URLs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding
   RewriteBase /
   should help
2. Change the rules to

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&des=$3 [N]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [F]
   ```

The final .htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&des=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: None of these lines of code can not direct me to what I want. It jums above rule #1 and can not match itself with the rule #2. So I get Forbidden message ...

Comment: You should remove the flags [N] and [F]

Comment: Did you try it yourself freytag?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get rid of the `N` and `F` flags. Not sure why you are getting redirected, it doesn't look like the rules you have are responsible for that. You also want to repeat the 2 conditions you have for both rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&des=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: again if I hint `http://localhost/project/product` I redirect to `http://localhost/` :(